# linear algebra transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

"Given a matrix $A$ = $[6\times 6 $matrix$]$, let $T$ : $\mathbb R^6$ → $\mathbb R^6$ be given by multiplying by this matrix..."

Can someone please help me understand questions like this, I have very little experience with linear algebra and anything can help.

When a question mentions "$T$: $\mathbb R^n$ → $\mathbb R^m$" it is talking about a transformation from the space $\mathbb R^n$ to another; $\mathbb R^m$ right?

When a questions gives a matrix $A$ (rather than a matrix $T$, that a set of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ is multiplied by to end up with vectors in $\mathbb R^m$. Do I have this idea right?) is matrix $A$ the same idea or am I completely mixing up two very different things?

[Original Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b7K2.png)

Also in regards to the original questions when they ask for dim(ker($T^2$)) etc. is that the same as calculating $A^2$ etc. and finding the kernel of that and then the dimension?

Comment: $T$ is a function which happens to be "linear", so we call it a "linear transformation".  $T$ is defined by
$$
T(x) = Ax
$$
that is all that is meant.

Comment: It is therefore notable that
$$
T^2(x) = T(T(x)) = A(Ax) = (AA)x = A^2 x
$$
so, the transformation $T^2$ is just the function $T^2(x) = A^2x$.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix represents a transformation with respect to a basis.  If you change the basis you change the matrix.  On $\Bbb R^n$ you have the standard basis which is what you usually use to associate a matrix to a transformation.  The transformation is then given by $V\mapsto AV$ where $A$ is $n\times m$ and $V$ is $m\times 1$.

Your question about the kernel is correct, you first square the matrix then find the dimension of its null space.

Comment: would the correct solutions for the original question be:

eigenvalues of T: λ = 0 with multiplicity 5 and λ = 1 with multiplicity 1, 
dim(ker($T$)) = 2 ,
dim(ker($T^2$)) = 4 ,
dim(ker($T^3$)) = 5 , and 
dim(ker($T$ - $I$)) = 1